# Why inside each dir there is a link to this dir itself?

Tags: directory

Inside each dir there is a link to this dir itself:

```
ls -a <any dir> | head -2
$.
$..
```

Question: for which purposes "." aka the link to itself exists?

Comment: It would be quite boring to specify the full path to the current directory when operating on it or on its files, not true?

Comment: Which kind of operation do you mean?

Comment: Execute the file in this directory is done with `./file`. Move a file from the directory above to this directory is `mv ../file .`. Of course, there are many other examples one can come up with.

Comment: . and .. are shortcuts for current directory and parent directory. If those did not exist you would need to type the whole path each time you would want to execute a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use `.` for the current directory when you issue a command, which takes the path to the directory as an argument. This way you can give its relative location instead of full path. An example of such command would be moving a file from another directory to the current directory:

```
mv ../file1 .
```

Also, if the program is not in your `$PATH`, you will need to specify its location to run it, even if you navigated to its directory, as Quasimodo pointed in the comment above:

```
./foo
```

Comment: Looks like @Quasimodo's comment..

Comment: I updated the answer after reading the comment, but I admit that my answer does not add much.

Comment: If someone makes a comment their loss ;-)  +1 Roman

Comment: No problem at all if you make an answer with my comment. Answers should be in answers, not in comments.